# Run a shell command on Objective c and simultaneously get output

Tags: objective-c, bash, macos, shell, nstask

Let's say I want to run `curl -o http://example.com/file.zip` via an Objective C app and I want to have a label or text box containing the download status which gets updated while the command is running. Maybe this could be achieved using dispatch_async, but now sure how. Before marking as duplicate, the methods I found, run the command, and **after** it has finished you get the output. I want to get the output while it's running, kinda like a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect a `NSPipe` to the `NSTask` using the `standardOutput` property and register to receive **Data Available** notifications.

```
@interface TaskMonitor: NSObject
@property NSPipe *outputPipe;
@end

@implementation TaskMonitor

-(void)captureStandardOutput:(NSTask *)process {

  self.outputPipe = [NSPipe new];
  process.standardOutput = self.outputPipe;

  //listen for data available
  [self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {

    NSData *output = self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData;
    NSString *outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // do something with the string chunk that has been received
      NSLog(@"-> %@",outputString);
    });

    //listen again...
    [self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

  }];

}

@end
```

Comment: Hello I just tried this but has a problem. It runs the whole command, and the output gets NSLogged, as it normaly would in any NSTask, and *after* that I get infinite `->` on the Logs with no data after it, except for the first one where it is like this `-> <!DOCTYPE html>`. As I said I want one `->` for every piece of data, so I can actually update the UI with it.

Comment: Nvm for some reason wasn't working on the log but worked when I connected it to the UI!